# xamarin multiple image picker error - ELCImagePicker not working for second time

Tags: xamarin.forms, elcimagepickercontroller

I am developing xamarin.forms PCL app.

I want to select multiple images from gallery so for ios I use ELCImagePicker.

Everything works fine when I open gallery for first time. But when I open it for second time(for e.g. changing selected image), app crashes. I use messaging center to pass my list of image paths to PCL project.

At second time, I receive messages multiple times and then I get FATAL SIGSEV error.

I have referred this [link](https://xamgirl.com/select-multiple-images-from-gallery-in-xamarin-forms/). And it has been very useful to people when I searched related multiple image picker on google.

Why is this happening ? Please help

Comment: if app from the link you provided works then there is something wrong with your code but how we can help if you didn't provide any? it looks like your app enters to the loop of messages. check that processing a message doesn't generate any recursive behavior.